# absolute position div disappers inside parrent div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am trying to put simple divs and arrange them, but my child div disappearing from parent div even though I am using parent div with relative and child div with absolute positioning. I want connect_us_01 and registeration divs insideheader_block1. I am working towards responsive webdesign. Many thanks.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aNzEB/)

```
<div id="header">
   <div id="header_block1">
       <div id ="registeration">reg</div>
       <div id ="connect_us_01">social media</div>
   </div>
   <div id="header_block2">
       <div id="crown_logo">logo</div>
       <div id="nav">navigation</div>
       <div class="contact_No_01">020324234233</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

### css

```
#header {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #ff6a00;
}
#header_block1 {
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 90%;
   background-color: pink;
}

#header_block2 {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 90%;
   position: relative;
   background-color: aqua;
}

/*----social media & connect us block*/
#connect_us_01 {
   position: absolute;
   width: 300px;
   height: 50px;
   right: 0;
   background-color: blue;
}
#registeration {
   position: absolute;
   left: 1px;
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: brown;
}
```

Comment: It would be exceptionally helpful if you could provide an idea of what you want the finished product to look like in terms of layout. In the meantime, just turn off `position:relative` in `#header_block2` to get your two `div`'s to rise above the rest.

Comment: I see only one `connect_us_01` . The other one is `contact_No_01` for which there appears no css

Comment: sorry my fault i mean connect us and registeration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elements with `position: absolute` are taken out of the content flow, meaning they have no inherent `height`. Since the children have no `height`, the parent gets no `height` either, rendering the children invisible. You could resolve it by giving the parent a static `height` (as in, for instance, `height: 100px`), but that's not very practical and not responsive at all.

What you're looking for isn't `position: absolute`; it's `float: left` and `float: right`. Apply those properties to the children and give the parent `overflow: hidden` (or whatever method of clearing floats works best with your layout) and it'll work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

To show block you refering to just add to `#header_block1` a `height` parameter also.

```
#header_block1  {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: @toxic: `overflow:hidden;`